# MSI mechanical keyboard gives wrong inputs on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm trying to use an MSI mechanical keyboard on my MacBook Pro, however, when using a keyboard tester the computer registers two inputs for one keyboard stroke (E.g. I press number 5 and the computer registers 5a). I've looked online but have not been able to find anyone else having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, I ended asking the manufacturer (MSI) and this particular keyboard does not support macOS. So better check next time.